# SQL profiler how to filter with EventClass column

Tags: profiler

I need to filter Profiler events by EventClass like RPC:completed, but I cannot find any filter for EventClass. Any idea how to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Event Classes cannot be filtered, instead you select which Event Classes to include in your trace and then filter events based on the properties of each Event Class.

For example, to exclude "RPC:Completed" from your trace, on the **Events Selection** tab, expand **Stored Procedures** and uncheck the box on the left-hand side of **RPC:Completed**.

To only "RPC:Completed" for a particular stored procedure, you click **Column Filters**, locate **ObjectName** and add your procedure name under *Like*.